# How to replace old text with new one between some specific lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

Like, I have a .txt like

```
Hello, this Stackoverflow
<! replace starts from here !>
Currently time is 7:27 pm.
<! replace ends here !>

Have a nice day.

<! replace starts from here !>
Thanks Devs...
<! replace ends here !>
```

I want the above .txt file as :-

```
Hello, this Stackoverflow
<! replace starts from here !>
Stackoverflow helps us very much.
<! replace ends here !>

Have a nice day.

<! replace starts from here !>
Thanks Developers.....
<! replace ends here !>
```

But I can't use the below code as the lines between `<! replace starts here !>` and `<! replace ends here !>` can be any random text.

```py
text = open("file.txt").read()
new_text = text.replace("Currently time is 7:27 pm.", "Stackoverflow helps us very much.") #like this for each
```

Hope,I am able to make you get what I am trying to say.

Please guide me with any way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried segmenting your file by sentences rather than by characters such as " " or "," but by the content of your txt file? Following this, if you discover one, you can simply process what you want on the splitted component that follows until you find the segment that ends the process of replacing. If this is acceptable to you, I may compose the response and receive credit for it.

Comment: Sir, can please explain this with a example for better understanding.....

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the text into a list of lines.
2. Find the first replacement marker; store its index.
3. Find the second replacement marker; store its index.
4. Cut out the entries in the list between the first and second index.
5. Insert new lines beginning at the first index.
6. Join and output the modified lines.

Comment: Can you please explain it with an example for better understanding....